# Enable compatibility mode for command prompt in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, administrator

I wanted to do something as simple as creating a link to run command promt as an administrator. So I created the link, but when I right-click>Properties>Compatibility all options are grayed out, and I can't set to run as administrador.

Right-click>"run as admin" still works, but I wanted a link that did it automatically.

(yes I'm running an admin account)

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create shortcut for cmd.exe and

```
open shortcut properties -> shortcut (tab) -> advance -> run as administrator
```